# How to add opencv compiler to dev c++ 5.6.2?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add OpenCV to Dev C++ for developing a project that uses image processing. But I am unable to find the exact steps for installing OpenCV on the current version of Dev C++ (5.6.2).

Any leads as to how to integrate it with Visual Studio 2013 will also be appreciated.

Comment: better restrict it to one compiler / ide for now, ask a different q. for the other.

Comment: i need to code in dev c++ and opencv has the required headers for coding   (image processing header files)

Comment: better use something like codeblocks, which is supported by cmake, so you can *generate* your projects. in any way, if you decide to use mingw as a compiler, you will have to *build* the opencv libs for that first.